# Adding methods to records type from Delphi in DWScript

Tags: delphi, methods, records, dwscript

After I've created a TRecordSymbol, how do I add a constructor and methods to it? I've tried using TMethodSymbol with little success, as I can't find a way to define the execution of the method.

Comment: First obvious thing to confirm: Does DWScript even support records with methods in the first place? Just because the host program's language supports a feature doesn't mean an embedded scripting language supports the same thing, no matter how similar the two languages might look syntactically.

Comment: I know it's supported, I just don't know how to register them correctly from the Delphi-end. Ref: http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/wiki/Records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method symbols (like all TFuncSymbol) defer the execution to an interface (defined through the Executable property) for "normal" execution (ie. with a stack frame and parameters evaluated and pushed on the stack). "Magic" function symbols on the other hand require a dedicated expression class, and they take over the whole function call (so less overhead, but you've got to guard yourself against everything).

For samples, you can look at what the dwsMathComplex & 3d units do, they introduce records with custom methods.

Comment: Is there a way to hide the magic functions from scripts/completion so they can only be used as methods?

Comment: If you want to filter out functions, you can filter out all TFuncSymbol that aren't a TMethodSymbol, or do you only want to filter out only magic functions? Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Sorry, I should be more clear. In dwsMathComplex for example, several internal functions, which are magic functions if I recall correctly, are added to the system. They're then added as operators for TComplex. What I want to do in such a situation is prevent the original functions from being accessible or visible, but still allow them to be used as operators. Because having, in this case, a separate function available on top of the operators feels rather messy.

Comment: Filtering those is a bit more complex, as I assume you want to filter only those and not all the magic functions. You have to look for TFuncSymbol whose Executable interface is implemented by a TComplexOpExpr, so something like "(sym is TFuncSymbol) and (TFuncSymbol(sym).Executable is TComplexOpExpr)".
An alternative would be to use the new TOperators.EnumerateOperatorSymbols method to enumerate all operator symbols, from whill you'll be able to obtain the list of all expressions that have an operator associated to them (so you can filter the related functions from the suggestions)

Comment: That sounds good. Once I know which are used by the operators, how do I prevent them from being accessed in scripts? What I'm looking for would be like the equivalent of assigning an action to be executed directly to the operator rather than redirecting the call to a function symbol. Of course if that's not possible, I suppose I could just filter them out of the code completion results.

Comment: Operators are just syntax sugar around function calls (so that they get proper names in call stacks, etc.), so you can't really forbid the function, you can however make them less accessible, either by masking them in the suggestions, or by moving them to a unit the uses won't "uses".